# MPEG DASH partial segment(s)

Tags: html, mpeg-dash, media-source

When the DASH segments are sent over network, it is possible that some of them are not completely received. In my application, if an incomplete segment is given to the player(HTML5 video with MSE), it just stops instead of skipping the segment and moving on to the next segment. Why is it so and how to handle such a case of partial segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When appending media segments with MSE, by default, the browser uses the timestamps of the frames in the segment to place them on the timeline at the right time. This may be useful when segments arrive out-of-order to make sure that the frames are laid out correctly. In your case, if you have incomplete segments, the player sees gaps in the timeline and pauses. The pausing behavior is the same as when the browser downloads and plays progressively a file: if not enough data has arrived to continue the playback, the player pauses until more data arrives. To avoid that you can either monitor the buffer status using the [`buffered` attribute](http://w3c.github.io/media-source/#widl-SourceBuffer-buffered) and re-request the missing segment parts, if you can. You can also use the [`sequence` mode](http://w3c.github.io/media-source/#idl-def-AppendMode.sequence) to append the segments, if you are sure that you append them in order.